# How can I present a yes/no question to a user prior to them submitting a background job?

Tags: website-design, confirmation, dialog, question-answer

I am a programmer by training and I often find that I have writer's block when I come across certain presentation issues.

I have a piece of software that links a seller user up with his account in an online marketplace. One of the items that frequently comes up is the need to import data from the online marketplace, and export to it.

Right now I accomplish this by presenting the user with "Import" and "Export" buttons. but now I need to capture whether the user wants to `replace` the data on either side, or merely `append` to it.

A button interface doesn't accomplish this. I need to ask the question, probably with a check-box. But I am completely stumped as to how to present this in a user interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you have a relatively simple problem in terms of what you want to ask your users, so why not ask it explicitly with four options (where I would **emphasise the safest option** for each).

So `Import and Append` and `Export and Append` would be the most common options I presume.  The other options can either be **de-emphasised text**, another button.

So something like:
[image]

Comment: This is so far from anything that would ever occur to me. Great!